# C++ error upon compliation

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have this method and the error is:

> `\Supp.cpp:35:6: attention : variable 'temp' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`

I don't understand why.

```
void parcourir_index(int * vec){
  int i;
  int temp;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    temp = vec[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: That's just a warning. You never used `temp` after you assigned `vec[i]` to it.

Comment: Because it is set, but not used :-)

Comment: Do you have warnings as errors turned on?

Comment: okay its a warnning but it don' want to work

Comment: how do i make i try to initializayed temp befor it doesn't work ??

Comment: chris i had use it look i put the value of the vec[i] in the variable temp

Comment: The compiler is telling you all you need to know. It's a warning: "variable 'temp' set but not used" i.e. You're setting it but not using it. If you want the warning to go away, use `temp` or get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because temp is a local variable, and there is no reference of it after'temp=vec[i]', the compiler will consider temp as redundent, and it will be eliminated by a pass called **Dead Code Elimination**.

Comment: so how i have to do to solve the probleme please

Comment: @Benomar yacine It depends on how do you plan to use temp

Comment: @Benomaryacine: What is the problem? Why did you declare `temp` in the first place, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: its only a variable that i use in that moment because i am making a progamme who ill caculate the the time of eeution so i put th values in temp juste for beeing able to execte the my other methode who will calculate me the time